# Mapping by request's body use two matches

Tags: wiremock

I has http request with body:

```
 endpoint = http://127.0.0.1:54400/json
reqBody:
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    "action": "Handler:GET_DICTIONARY",
    "locale": "ro",
    "data": {"dictionary_type":"MTS"}
}
```

I need to get stubbed response.
Here my Wiremock mapping:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "bodyPatterns": [
      {
        "contains": "Handler:GET_DICTIONARY"
      }
    ]
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "fixedDelayMilliseconds": 3000,
    "bodyFileName": "t2a/micb/webclient/_mts_response.json"
  }
}
```

But I has **many** another requests that content request's body with text:

```
"Handler:GET_DICTIONARY"
```

So as result I need to mapping also by

```
"dictionary_type":"MTS"
```

because text

and
`"dictionary_type":"MTS"` **AND** `"Handler:GET_DICTIONARY"` create **UNIQUE** request.

So how I can mapping by request's body use this two matches?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add "matchesJsonPath" in addition to your "contains"

```
"bodyPatterns": [
        {
            "matchesJsonPath": "$.data[?(@.dictionary_type == 'MTS')]"
        }
]
```

That will guarantee that all the request with dictionary_type = MTS will mapped to that response.